# Single or two-stage replacement in two zone system

Tags: air-conditioning, central-air, zoned-heating

Need to replace an 18 year old single stage, two zoned furnace/AC installed in my converted attic in Chicago.  It's in the knee wall and serves the attic and the second floor.  Air returns on both floors, generally one duct into each bedroom.  No bypass duct installed and no room to put one in.  House was built in 1914 - converted attic is well insulated but I don't think there's any insulation behind the plaster walls that haven't been touched.  We just moved into the house so I don't know how well this system works.

I've had three people come out to give estimates and it looks like I've got a number of options:

1. Keep current design

   - install single stage furnace and compressor
   - keep zoning intact
   - hope that it heats and cools evenly
   - two out of three installers and the rest of the Internet do not advocate this option
   - problems include too much cooling when only one zone is on
2. Remove zoning

   - install single stage furnace and compressor
   - replace automatic dampers with manual ones
   - install thermostat with remote temp sensors
   - one installer recommends this option - says I might need to run the fan more often
     (or maybe continuously) to keep temps even
3. Install two stage furnace and compressor

   - could potentially work better when only one zone is asking, but
   - still have problem of too much cooling if thermostat requests both stages and only
     one zone is on
   - I was thinking that you could add some relays to enable the second stage only when both
     zones were asking for cooling (configure thermostats as single stage - second stage only
     from relay)
   - or perhaps there are new fancy zone controllers that will do this automatically?
4. Install fancy multi-stage system

   - replaces zone controls with new stuff
   - not really an option because it's too much money
5. Something else?

Am I overthinking this?  I'm leaning towards option 3, but will it work as well as I think or am I missing something?  Is number one really as bad as people say? The guy who owned this house before me was a contractor and almost everything else seems to be done right...

Hopefully this isn't too vague!

Thanks
Pete

Comment: Do you have room in the basement?  One in the basement and one in the attic (of whatever type -- single, dual or multiple stage) is frequently done with old houses (including ours.)

Comment: Did/does the existing one do an adequate job to keep the wife happy? If not, I'd say option 3. If so, why not keep the design configuration and replace the dead/dying items with identical units? I think 2-stage is good. You might also want to consider variable-speed blower.

Comment: There is another 2 zone system in the basement that services the basement and first floor. That one has one foot in the grave but it’s not dead yet. Maybe another year or two.

Comment: Chicago? You gotta see this on heat pumps. Really.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFEHFsO-XSI